# NFS mount has stopped working on ESXi

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, storage, nfs

We have had around 20 hosts connected to an NFS share running from an Ubuntu server. The other day they all lost connection. We have rebooted the NFS server to rule out any services going funny.

When trying to connect to the mount, this is the log from the Ubuntu side syslog, which looks fine:

```
May 14 16:23:26 nas1 snmpd[2351]: Connection from UDP: [192.168.99.51]:36999->[192.168.99.41]
May 14 16:23:45 nas1 rpc.mountd[1863]: authenticated mount request from 192.168.30.1:604 for /data/nfs (/data/nfs)
```

And this is the log from the vmkernel.log on the ESX server:

```
2013-05-14T15:29:25.882Z cpu6:9124)NFS: 157: Command: (mount) Server: (nas1.4d.wirehive.int) IP: (192.168.30.51) Path: (/data/nfs) Label: (NFS) Options: (None)
2013-05-14T15:29:25.882Z cpu6:9124)StorageApdHandler: 692: APD Handle b4215f5c-3ba55d8f Created with lock[StorageApd0x41001d]
2013-05-14T15:29:25.887Z cpu6:9124)NFS: 1236: NFS FSINFO failed with NFS status 70 (Invalid handle) on Server (192.168.30.51) Path (/data/nfs)
2013-05-14T15:29:25.887Z cpu6:9124)StorageApdHandler: 739: Freeing APD Handle [b4215f5c-3ba55d8f]
2013-05-14T15:29:25.887Z cpu6:9124)StorageApdHandler: 802: APD Handle freed!
2013-05-14T15:29:25.887Z cpu6:9124)NFS: 218: NFS mount nas1.4d.int:/data/nfs status: Unable to query remote mount point's attributes
```

Looks like the problems start with:

```
NFS FSINFO failed with NFS status 70
```

What does this mean? I can provide any required logs.

Comment: Did you reboot the ESXi host as well?  NFS clients often get extremely wonky if the NFS server reboots on them.

Comment: I'll give that a go on one of the hosts.

Comment: Nope no joy, same thing.

Comment: The VMware KB might be of some assistance. [link](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1007352)  The command in there that looks promising is `# esxcfg-nas -a <datastore name> -o <nfs server hostname/ip> -s <mount point>`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I run into NFS issues with ESXi I work my way through this KB article:
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003967

```
$ vmkping - I
```

is pretty great since you can isolate which `vmkernel` you want to use.

Also, if you're running ESXi 4.x or later `nc` (aka. netcat) is great for making sure there are no firewall issues.

For you, try something like:

```
$ nc -z 192.168.30.51 2049
```